# How to reject merge request in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there any way in GitLab UI to reject a merge request because code has issue?

If not what is the right way to track this?

Comment: Is this a self-hosted instance, or on https://gitlab.com?

Comment: gitlab.com instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always close the merge request without merging the branches. However, the standard workflow is that, if you find some issues with the code, you can comment the specific lines of code if you go to "Changes" or comment the whole merge request and suggest possible improvements. Then the developer can resolve those code issues you found. That is what merge requests are for.

Comment: Is it not possible to "block" a PR from being merged if changes are requested? In GitHub after done with a review, you can "comment" or "approve" or "request changes" on the PR/MR.  If changes are requested it prevents the PR from being merged.  Does GitLab have this same feature?

Comment: @PhilLucks, in the project settings under General -> Merge requests you can check „All discussions must be resolved“. This will cause open threads, that have not been marked as resolved, to prevent the merge request from being merged.

Comment: What if there's a merge request that's not supposed to be merged? maybe it targets the wrong branch and we don't want it in our branch.

Comment: What if... can go on forever.  Simply stated, rejecting a PR should be an option - if there is a what if that means there is more than one option.

Comment: Merge requests are there for deciding whether the changes should be merged at all - in the first place. And if not, there has to be a way of effective protecting of the codebase. Resolving discussions or threads is a very weak measure, nowhere close to being a safety guard. The author can as well mark those as resolved without actually resolving them.

Comment: The suggested answer is a makeshift operation. Gitlab should allow an option to block a diff. Period.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with Phil Lucks. In my opinion gitlab is missing functionality. A merge request is a *request* and as such should be able to be rejected/denied.

The following thread gives insight into the thought process that was going on with Closing a request versus denying one. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/23355

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

IMHO GitHub's PR system prefers repo maintainer, i.e. PRs are for them to "pull changes" when they want.

On the other hand, GitLab's MR system prefers contributors, i.e. they have all the rights to "merge changes".

Unfortunately the only thing you can do is to protect your branch(es), set MR approval as mandatory, leave comments to request changes, and close the MR if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab 16.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/02/15/gitlab-16-9-released/#request-changes-on-merge-requests) (February 2024) reminds us of an option which should help to block the MR:

> ### Request changes on merge requests
>
> The last part of reviewing a merge request is communicating the outcome. While approving was unambiguous, leaving comments was not. They required the author to read your comments, then determine if the comments were purely informational, or described needed changes. Now, when you complete your review, you can select from three options:
>
> - **Comment**: Submit general feedback without explicitly approving.
> - **Approve**: Submit feedback and approve the changes.
> - **Request changes**: Submit feedback that should be addressed before merging.
>
> The sidebar now shows the outcome of your review next to your name. Currently, ending your review with **Request changes** doesn’t block the merge request from being merged, but it provides extra context to other participants in the merge request.
>
> You can leave feedback about the **Request changes** feature in our [feedback issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/438573).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_9/create-request-changes-merge-requests.png -- Request changes on merge requests]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#submit-a-review) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/11719).